# Getting null object in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to robotframework. I am working on application where i need to automate the test cases. I am downloading eclipse client from server to my desktop and then update the plugin. I am trying to access an object, but i get null everytime. i checked the flow. we are using osgi framework for doing this. activator class is called and the object which i require is loaded through load method. when i try to get the object back i get null. when i try to get the object just after loading i get it, but not from framework.

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the framework you are using but there must be some kind of dependency injection behind the scenes. You probably don't use the same configuration/object-creator in and out of the test case. **Verify the flow which creates the object and analyze the same flow in Robot Framework. And spot the differences.**

If you need more help edit your question specifying how the object is created and how you expect that to work in the test case.